# Generics with parameterized collections?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a version of the HashMap that doesn't replace the value if a duplicate key is entered, but actually adds the two corresponding values together. The key value must be of type `Number` so that adding can occur. However, it doesn't seem to understand that my `V` is of type `Number`, or at least it does until I try to call `super.put`. It's as if the `V` in `HashMap` is not actually the same `V` as the one that I declared to `extend Number`.

What is going on here?

```
public class AdditiveMap<K, V extends Number> extends HashMap<K, V>
{
    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value)
    {
        if (containsKey(key))
            // Second param Found 'Number', required 'V'
            super.put(key, (Number)(get(key).intValue() + value.intValue()));
        else 
            super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The message is saying that `Integer` is not the same as `V`, which is of course correct.

Comment: Is that not what the `merge` method is designed for in the `Map` interface?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `V` extends Number

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean that it's an `Integer`.  (For example, what if `V` is `Double`?)

Comment: There wouldn't be a need to cast to a `(Number)` if this were logically correct, the int would be boxed and widened automatically..

Comment: @AndyTurner nope, won't work. see here: http://i.imgur.com/JvUMj3v.png

Comment: @Hatefiend OK... but it doesn't work with the cast either, does it? It can't be an `int`, it can't be a `Number`, it has to be a `V`.

Comment: @AndyTurner But `Number` is a class that `extends` `Number`, surely?

Comment: It is. But `V` could be `Number`, `Integer`, `Double` etc etc. You can't put a `Number` into a `Map<String, Integer>` directly (e.g. `Number n = 1; new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("", n);`), you can't here either for the same reason.

Comment: Oh.... I get it. So basically I would have had to say `public class AdditiveMap<K, Number> extends HashMap<K, Number>`?

Comment: @Hatefiend exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't create a `Map` which does this in the `put` method. The contract of the [`Map.put` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) is (emphasis mine):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, **the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

As such, your map would violate the contract of the interface.

You are, of course, free to add a `AdditiveMap.addValuesTogether` (or whatever) method. But you'd be best off just using the existing [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
map.merge(key, newValue, v -> v + newValue);
```

The main advantage of this is that this same syntax works for all numeric types (well, for `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`; you'd need a cast for `short`, `char` and `byte` because they are widened to `int` when you add them; you could avoid the explicit cast by using `v -> v += newValue`); but you actually can't do what you're trying to do generically (without providing a `Merger<V>` strategy, which can add a `V` to another `V`; and that's just very heavyweight compared to using this existing method).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will use this approach. Can you tell me why the original way of going about it is poor? Thanks.